# Bootstrap 4 - Fixed bottom message box within col (slack-like interface)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a Slack-like interface with a fixed position message box at the bottom using Bootstrap 4.  If I try to use the `fixed-bottom` class (where my custom `message-box` col is), it takes up the entire window width which I don't want since there's a sidebar.  It also covers up the scroll button in the bottom right.  I've seen some solutions using `position-sticky fixed-bottom` but that doesn't seem to work here.  I'm new to HTML/CSS so I'm not sure if I'm even using the right hierarchy in terms of rows/cols and I'm only vaguely familiar with using `vh-100`, `mh-100`, and `flex-grow-1`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-lg px-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_links"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_links">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="col-2 mh-100 overflow-auto py-2 d-none d-lg-block">
      <h6>Sidebar</h6>
      <ul class="nav flex-column bg-info rounded">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='col mh-100 overflow-auto'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col">
          <h3>Body content</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row flex-grow-1'>
        <div class="col mh-100 py-2">
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
          <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col message-box position-sticky fixed-bottom py-2">
          <div class="input-group ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/0re4jf2qky)

Comment: What you are asking for cannot be done without a "hacky" solution.  You have to have `position:fixed` for it to always be at the bottom of the viewport.  This takes it out of the document flow so there really is no way to also contain it to only the right column.  You could fix it to the bottom right and give it a width of 83.33333% but that won't stop the content from flowing behind it.  You would have to also give it a white background and create a new div at the bottom of the right column with a fixed height that is the same as the input height. Then media query for when sidebar disappears.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "hacky" solution as I described in my comment above.  You can see it in action in [this codeply snippet](https://www.codeply.com/p/1ZnZoCPUEu).

**EDIT**:  I've updated the codeply with a custom scrollbar with a fixed width.  Using CSS Calc to account for the fixed scrollbar width and responsive element width.

jQuery -->

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $("body").addClass("up top");
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $("body").addClass("down bottom");
    }
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $("body").removeClass("up top");
        } else {
            $("body").addClass("up top");
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $("body").addClass("down bottom");
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("down bottom");
        }
    });
});
```

css -->

```
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 17px;
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #a3a3a3;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background-color: #505050;
}

body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
}

/* Up */
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowup.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.up::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowupup.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.scrollbar:not(.top)::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowuphov.jpg);
}

/* Down */
body.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdown.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.down::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdowndown.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

body.scrollbar:not(.bottom)::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
    background-image: url(https://www.golden-painting.com/styles/images/scrollarrowdownhov.jpg);
}

.fixed-right {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 17px;
    width: calc(83.333333% - 17px);
    background: white;
}

.footer-spacer {
    height: 74px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .fixed-right {
        width: calc(100% - 17px);
    }
}
```

html -->

```
<body class="scrollbar up">
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-lg px-0">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_links" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_links">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="col-2 mh-100 overflow-auto py-2 d-none d-lg-block">
                <h6>Sidebar</h6>
                <ul class="nav flex-column bg-info rounded">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col mh-100 scrollbar overflow-auto">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h3>Body content</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row flex-grow-1">
                    <div class="col mh-100 py-2">
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                        <div class="footer-spacer"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 offset-lg-2 fixed-right message-box py-2">
                <div class="input-group ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for this answer.  I think I was able to accomplish something similar using bootstraps built-in classes.  Basically using `fixed-bottom` and some `offset-*-*` breakpoints so that the message box stays the same width as the right column.  Here's [the codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/0re4jf2qky) if you want to check it out.  I guess my last question is - is there anyway to have the bottom-right scroll button shown on top of the message box?  In both of our solutions it is covered up which looks hacky.

Comment: Well yes, but that will be some more hacky sh*t.

Comment: The [width of the scrollbar](https://codepen.io/sambible/post/browser-scrollbar-widths?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=d55acdce78eda46364e1ebc3fee668a9dbf02972-1592399067-0-AVbz_LQ8PLnaUZGKnJTEqIldjhep4BnysELS8SfQwj0NStA1Hj1_W9diu_wzRQG3c1EiCZmkUu4kROToKZweuQS8o9hCiX4a9KKSOw10-HCb0fzu64zJ1XqnG0A0bCAccZ9m85zJ2MxQwF__tJgW2ujFalL3xlfU_3FMLn6263Q6EJGhRA5IjR1MKRkkGS-Te2YApLMrKi7t4nxAHB_hVDPyFaNUUzq_OzFL08dBjiWWF3M4mZ6Zj3Vx_-lH6xJh0SSJMhq2XrzBiJif3ZNZJTyiqEKEjXT7B-KB-NH_i_fccluNdcKiiaPWYo8pdW2jiLAxEhc1zHtTS4xaHDcQy89GFw-UECK_z7V4YDGxlwL8SCLDHKHFYi5-DVLBMOf40Q) is different on different browsers and os's

Comment: You can [set the width of the scrollbar](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar-width/) so it is the same across all browsers and os's but if you don't use a percentage width, you will have an issue with responsiveness because you will be trying to change the percentage of your offset to match a fixed pixel width of the scrollbar.  If you use a percentage width of the scrollbar to combat that issue, then you will have a scrollbar that changes width based on browser width and may look strange.

Comment: I'm not sure if the width of the scrollbar is relevant (maybe it is?).  I think it's more related to the _height_ of the scrollbar, or moreso the height of the scrollable column?  The top of the scroll bar does not overlay the navbar.  I'd like the bottom part to do the same, so that you can see the 'down' button right above the send button of the message box.  So the scrollable column should stack on top of the message box, instead of stretching to the bottom of the screen and going behind the message box.  Is that possible?  Again I'm new to laying out web pages so I really don't know.

Comment: It would be nice if you could just add a margin to the bottom of the scrollbar to get it above the fixed element but you cannot.  The reason the navbar doesn't cover it is because the navbar is still in the flow of the document (DOM).  It has `position:relative`.  It appears "fixed" at the top because of `display:flex`.  If you uncheck that property in DevTools, you will see the navbar scroll off the screen with the rest of the content.  I've updated [my mdbootstrap snippet](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/milkytech/2205935) with my "hacky" solution.  The arrows need some work

Comment: I put it in [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/1ZnZoCPUEu).  That site is even better than mdbootstrap for testing code with bootstrap resources. +1 for that!  I also put it [on the actual web](https://www.golden-painting.com/test-bootstrap.html).  The problem with some of the bootstrap built-in classes is that by the time you figure out which ones you need, it's easier just to write your own class.

Comment: I am starting to see what you mean with the using bootstrap vs rolling your own thing.  If you want to update your answer with your most recent codeply I will accept it as the answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just updated the answer and codeply.  I created my own arrow images to get very close to the stock chrome scrollbar.  Some more will need to be done with javascript to get the behavior exactly the same.  For instance, with stock, there is no hover event on the arrow and the arrow color changes when the thumb is up against it.  Also, the thumb has a hover color change and then an even darker color change while holding the click on the thumb!  Both will require javascript.

Comment: I actually just took care of the double color change of the thumb with css `:active`.  Now to tackle the arrows with javascript!

Comment: I now have it perfectly emulating the Chrome scrollbar with some javascript. See it [on the web](https://www.golden-painting.com/test-bootstrap/marcus/2/).  I will update the answer and codeply with the full code.